# Where should I start in making industry standard audio in my iPhone applications?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, openal

I am trying to get started in advanced audio with the iPhone SDK. I really want to make professional level audio components. I know the basics (e.g. how to use NSAVAudioPlayers), but I don't know what to do for the more complicated sort of audio (e.g. osculation and audio cones). Does anyone know where to go for this? (I tried research online, and all that came up weer the sort of simplistic audio components).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Core Audio](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html). That's where you'll find an OpenAL implementation. You might also want to look at the Audio Processing Graph API (also part of core audio).